# How to find out which driver is handling a device in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers

while trying to understand what a specific application is doing i stumbled upon a windows api call, named `DeviceIoControl`.
It writes to a file called `\\\\.\\EnergyDrv`.

Looks like this is a file created by a driver to me, right?
Because that's what DeviceIoControl is doing.

Is there a way to find out which driver is reading from / has created that "file"?

---

P.S. if this question should be closed in your eyes, tell me how I can improve it instead of downvoting please.

Comment: `CreateFile` is short for *CreateFileHandle*, not a file. Files are abstracted things, ie you can treat many non file things as files, all you need is a file handle. Your driver is in the name, `EnergyDrv`.

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is no driver named energydrv :/

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew and look at parameter 1 and remarks. Download https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj

Comment: I don't have an *EnergyDrv* but do have a *GPUEnergyDrv* as both a driver and a device plus it is also in the global namespace. Its' description is *Energy Tracker*.

Comment: Type in an elevated command prompt. `SC` does drivers as well as services. `sc queryex EnergyDrv` and `sc qc energydrv` for more info.

Comment: well, using WinObj there is one entry under \device and one under GLOBAL??\ which is called energydrv, unfortunately thoese dont give me any further information. those both sc commands result in "not an installed service" :/

Comment: See if you can update drivers using Windows Update.

Comment: And if Windows' Update doesn't help go to your laptop or motherboard/videocard manufacturer and update drivers from there. Drivers from these sources (that aren't on Windows Update) haven't been tested by Microsoft (which costs money). They typically are higher performance but prone to errors more.